# Should the (non-SSD) drives in my server be constantly written to?

Tags: hard-drive

I ran `dstat` to get an idea of my system's performance.  One thing that struck me was, the disks are being very frequently (sometimes constantly) written to.  This is usually on the order of bytes, sometimes kilobytes, per second.  Nothing huge.

Is this bad for my disks?  Will they perhaps wear out faster because of this?  Or is this normal?

Update: this is a Raid 10 array with 8 10k drives.

Some output from dstat -d -f

```
  -dsk/sda--
 read  writ
 745B  159k
   0    52k
   0  1596k
   0     0 
   0    28k
   0     0 
   0     0 
   0   532k
   0     0 
   0     0 
   0    24k
   0    32k
   0   780k
   0     0 
   0    50k
   0     0 
   0     0 
   0   764k
   0     0 
   0     0
```

Comment: It's fine. Disks are a wear-part and expected to fail over time. Do you have any sort of RAID in place?

Comment: Can you provide some line from `dstat -d -f` and `iotop -a` ?

Comment: @shodanshok - I've included some dstat output, thanks

Comment: Ok, the write usage is quite low. Nothing wrong here :) Anyway, you can use `iotop` to identifying the writing processes.

Answer (score 2):

Disks are meant to be used. Assuming that you're using server-grade disks that are built for 24x7 duty cycle, you have nothing to worry about.